# how to find a value that's contains from value from other cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, excel-formula, contains

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($L$1:$L$100000,SMALL(IF(A$1=$H$1:$H$100000,ROW($L$1:$L$100000)- MIN(ROW($L$1:$L$100000))+1,""), ROW()-2)),"")
```

This is current code that I use now. it compare a1 to h1 to h100000 rows to see if h column has a1 value. If column H has a1 value it will show l column data.
However, I want to change code to, if column H contains(like) a1 then return data L data.

So I've tried below code to make that happen, but its not doing anything.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($L$1:$L$100000,SMALL(IF("*"&A$1&"*"=$H$1:$H$100000,ROW($L$1:$L$100000)- MIN(ROW($L$1:$L$100000))+1,""), ROW()-2)),"")
```

How can i make this code to make it work?

Comment: Show this in the context of some sample data. Start your question with that - it will be easier to interpret that way and you'll likely get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use AGGREGATE to retrieve the row number and SEARCH instead of wildcards for the substring in string location.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(L:L, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($1:$99999)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$1, H$1:H$99999)), ROW(1:1))), "")
```

SEARCH is not case-sensitive; reaplace SEARCH with FIND if a case-sensitive match is required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you tell me what does this part of code doing? AGGREGATE(15, 7,